# How to change text background inside in xml

Tags: android, xml, string, text, background

Let say I have next code in strings XML, which is working fine and text color become blue on output

```
<string name="hello_world">
    <font color='blue'> Hello world!</font> here is my text with yellow background 
</string>
```

Question - Is it possible to change **text background** for some worlds in similar way as above, **directly inside in xml string** ?

Final result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, Check this:

```
<string name="hello_world">
<font color='blue'> Hello world!</font><font color = 'black' bgcolor = 'yellow'> here is my text with yellow background</font>
</string>
```

Comment: I need to change only some WORDS, because TextView located in ListView

Comment: yeah, working in such way if the text directly in TextView.

Comment: But if I pass String variable thru the adapter into Array List not working...very interesting,... FONT COLOR is working good, but BGCOLOR not...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is - Just add the correct html tags in the xml string (just as you did) and then set the text to the `TextView` like this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.your_string), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
    yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.your_string)));
}
```